# Transpose Rows into column in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

i am having trouble to transpose row into  column as i wanted

having data like
rowid   error
1   4126
2   26
3   42
4   1451
5   12214126

wanted like

rowid   error       wanted like
1   4126        41
26
2   26      26
3   42      42
4   1451        14
51
5   12214126    12
21
41
26

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select error, regexp_extract_all(error, r'\d{2}') codes
from data
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it works for you. consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)